# Show that if $\{X_n\}$ is bounded above and no cluster points then $\lim X_n=-\infty$

Tags: real-analysis

$\lim X_n=-\infty$ if for any $M$ there exists $n_0$ s.t. $X_n<M$ for every $n>n_0$.

I am stuck on how to show that this limit is bounded above and that there are no cluster points so that the limit of $X_n$ is $-\infty$.

Answer (score 0):

Let $L$ be an upper bound and assume that not $\lim_ X_n=-\infty$. Then there exists $M$ such that for all $n_0$ there exists $n>n_0$ with $X_n\ge M$. Let $M'=\min\{M, X_1,\ldots,X_{n_0}\}-1$ Then $X_n>M'$ for all $n$. So $X_n$ is bounded both above (by $L$) and below (by $M'$), hence has a cluster point.

---

A variation on the above: Let $M$ be given. If $X_n\ge M$ for infinitely many $n$ then the infinite subsequence corresponding to these indices is bounded by $M$ below and $L$ above, hence has a cluster point, which is also a cluster point of the original sequence. Therefore almost all points are $\le M$, i.e. there exists $n_0$ such that $X_n<M$ for all $n>n_0$.

Comment: i need to show that there are NO cluster points for this limit